# jQuery UI Autocomplete using a static json file as source

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using **jquery-ui-autocomplete** (actually, a **catcomplete** attached to a search box). It works vey well as long as I use a static-defined array of items as source.

For performance reasons, I don't want the autocomplete to send Ajax requests to a PHP script making %like% requests to MySQL. So, **I generated a JSON file from the DB**, containing every item that can be matched in the search (about 20-30 items, from many sql tables). I'd like to **read/parse the file** only once, as the page loads or when the user starts to type in the search box.

**I'm stuck here.**
I tried to attach an Ajax call to the .catcomplete() (code below). I also tried to make a getJSON call and create the .catcomplete in its success() method. 
**Both ways fail silently.**

I'm kind of new to JS/jQuery stuff, I already like it, but I'm a bit lost. Any help/solution/pointer to usefull doc would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Here is the HTML : (real simple)

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" role="search">
    <input id="searchfield" />
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="go!" />
</form>
```

Here is my JS code :

```
$( "#searchfield" ).catcomplete({
delay: 0,
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/cache.json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {term: request.term},
        success: function(data) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.label,
                    category: item.category,
                    desc: item.desc
                };
            }));
        }
    });
},
minlength:0
});
```

Sample JSON data:

```
[
{ label: "lbl1", category: "cat1", desc: "desc1"}, 
{ label: "lbl2", category: "cat1", desc: "desc2"}, 
{ label: "lbl3", category: "cat1"}
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your datasource is throwing an parse error since the json format is not propper, in json the keys also have to be enclosed within `"`.

```
{
  "list" : [{
                "label" : "lbl1",
                "category" : "cat1",
                "desc" : "desc1"
            }, {
                "label" : "lbl2",
                "category" : "cat1",
                "desc" : "desc2"
            }, {
                "label" : "lbl3",
                "category" : "cat1"
            }]
}
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VCAqfAGg7NR0coUxb5uL)

If you want the request term based searches, then you will have to make some more changes

```
  var xhr;
  $( "input" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      var regex = new RegExp(request.term, 'i');
      if(xhr){
        xhr.abort();
      }
      xhr = $.ajax({
          url: "data.json",
          dataType: "json",
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            response($.map(data.list, function(item) {
              if(regex.test(item.label)){
                return {
                    label: item.label,
                    category: item.category,
                    desc: item.desc
                };
              }
            }));
          }
      });
    },
    minlength:0
  });
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qxisjz41PcA2LlcOUg5U?p=preview)

Comment: Actually, I managed to skip the regexp part using a monkeypatch on _renderItemData (which seem to involve only the matching items). I marked your answer as the best one as my real problem was the quotes in the JSON file. Thank you very much for pointing that out !

Answer (score 10):

Try flipping it around, so on page-load you grab it once, then instantiate the autocomplete.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/cache.json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {term: request.term},
        success: function(data) {
            var cat_data = $.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.label,
                    category: item.category,
                    desc: item.desc
                };
            });
            $("#searchfield").catcomplete({
                delay: 0,
                source: cat_data,
                minlength:0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer was helpful to me (thank you very much). Actually, I had a problem with the JSON file (lack of "" around properties names...), this syntax helped me to point that out. Everything works fine. Thanks again !

Comment: great tip, specially for larger JSON files!

Comment: @joe-frambach Can we use limit with this syntax. Let's say every time I need max 10 results?