# Calling JSon file with ajax(Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Brand new to using JSon/ajax. Trying to replicate this [jQuery UI Autocomplete using a static json file as source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15695931/jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-a-static-json-file-as-source) just as an example. I'm not positive I'm referencing this correctly if someone could let know whats wrong. Getting a (Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined)

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" role="search">
                <input id="searchfield" />
                <input type="submit" name="go" value="go!" />
            </form>


<script src='js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/autocomplete/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/Providers.json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {term: request.term},
        success: function(data) {
            var cat_data = $.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                    ProviderID: item.ProviderID,
                    Name: item.Name,                  
                };
            });
            $("#searchfield").catcomplete({
                delay: 0,
                source: cat_data,
                minlength:0
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

json format

```
   {"Providers":[{"ProviderID":"3","NAME":"name1"}, 
    {"ProviderID":"4","NAME":"name2"},  
    {"ProviderID":"5","NAME":"name3"}]}
```

Comment: request is not defined. So what are you expecting request to be?! From where you copied this code you should be able to find where `request` is defined...

Comment: The message is pretty clear: `request.term` (request is not defined)

Comment: is 'request' a function in the jquery file? What do I need to replace it with?

Comment: @user1 Request is an object, test by replacing it by a string firstly: `{term: "anything i want to search for"}` But if you have no idea what you are looking for, please start by reading some basic tutos

Answer (score 0):

This particular `data: {term: request.term},` is the problem

You need to define any javascript variable before accessing them.

```
 var request;
```

In your case `data` is not required. Just remove `data: {term: request.term}` since you are loading the static `.json` file

Comment: What would I replace request with? I assumed that was a function from the jQuery file.

Comment: `data` is to send parameters to the server. I guess you can remove it

Comment: removing it gives me more erros, please see my comments on the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a reading json file, it is clear there is no need to pass any parameter.  So remove `data: {term: request.term}`

Comment: get more errors removing it: OPTIONS file:///C:/Users/jswanson/Desktop/Survey/json/Providers.json No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: also this one: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/jswanson/Desktop/Survey/json/Providers.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Ajax is the act of making HTTP requests from JavaScript. Stop trying to do it without HTTP. Run a web server.

Comment: @user1 this is called CORS..  you can overcome by changing dataType from json to` jsonp` or nove on to web servers.

Comment: only change the dataType and nothing else? still getting similar errors.

Comment: @user1 you're trying to call local file via your js file.  Hence you're suffering from CORS.  If you're already hosting in web server put this json file there.

Comment: I understand however I'm not hosting a web server. This is being done locally. Changing to jsonp still gives me those errors if everything thing else is correct i assume.

Comment: @user1 remaining code is right..  also here ia question which is closely related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865938/unable-to-load-xml-from-external-file-using-jquery

Comment: I think the problem was chrome I do not see the same warning in explorer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396527/error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-when-loading